# Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `Card -> Bool'

Tags: haskell

There is my code:

```
data Suit = Spade | Heart | Diamond | Club deriving (Eq, Show)
data CVal = Ace | King | Queen | Jack | Ten | Nine | Eight | Seven | Six | Five | Four | Three | Two deriving Show
data Card = Card Suit CVal deriving Show

sameSuit :: Card -> Card -> Bool
sameSuit (Card Spade _) (Card Spade _)     = True
sameSuit (Card Heart _) (Card Heart _)     = True
sameSuit (Card Diamond _) (Card Diamond _) = True
sameSuit (Card Club _) (Card Club _)       = True
sameSuit (Card x _) (Card y _)             = False

getNumber :: Card -> Int
getNumber (Card _ Two)   = 2
getNumber (Card _ Three) = 3
getNumber (Card _ Four)  = 4
getNumber (Card _ Five)  = 5
getNumber (Card _ Six)   = 6
getNumber (Card _ Seven) = 7
getNumber (Card _ Eight) = 8
getNumber (Card _ Nine)  = 9
getNumber (Card _ Ten)   = 10
getNumber (Card _ Jack)  = 11
getNumber (Card _ Queen) = 12
getNumber (Card _ King)  = 13
getNumber (Card _ Ace)   = 14

beats :: Card -> Card -> Bool
beats x y = if sameSuit (x y) && getNumber(x) > getNumber(y) then True else False
```

Error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `Card -> Bool'
In the return type of a call of `sameSuit'
In the first argument of `(&&)', namely `sameSuit (x y)'
In the expression: sameSuit (x y) && getNumber (x) > getNumber (y)
```

I don't understand why i can't call function "sameSuit" in finction "beats". If I call it from prelude, like prelude > sameSuit (Card Club 10) (Card Club Ace) it returns right value and function type is Bool, not "Card -> Bool". What i do wrong? Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: As an aside: `if blahblahblah then True else False` can (and should) be shortened to `blahblahblah`.

Comment: You can write `sameSuit` much simpler: `sameSuit (Card x _) (Card y _) = x == y`.

Comment: If you reverse the order of the constructors in `CVal` and derive `Ord` you don't need the `getNumber` function in `beats`, you could just use `x > y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A corrected implementation of `beats` is:

```
beats x y = (sameSuit x y) && (getNumber x > getNumber y)
```

So, you *can* call `sameSuit` in `beats`, but you have to use parens.

**Edit**: Actually, you don't need the parens. In your code you were calling `sameSuit (x y)`, but you have to call it without parens: `sameSuit x y`

Comment: Never, ever write `if c then True else False`, the `if` is totally redundant.  Write `c`.

Answer (score 3):

In `beats` you appear to be trying to call several functions as `function(args)`, using C-like syntax. Haskell does not use this syntax; function application is written by simple token adjacency, with parentheses only needed for nested expressions.

`getNumber(x)` is harmless, but pointless. It is parsed as the application of a function `getNumber` to a parenthesised expression `(x)`, which is of course equivalent to just `getNumber x`, so it does what you want.

`sameSuit (x y)` is parsed as the application of a function `sameSuit` to a single argument, the parenthesised expression `(x y)`. The sub-expression is in turn the application of a function `x` to `y`, which makes no sense in this context as `x` is a `Card`, not a function. You need to supply two arguments for `sameSuit`, as in `sameSuit x y`.

Since `sameSuit` is of type `Card -> Card -> Bool`, `sameSuit` supplied with only a single argument is of type `Card -> Bool`. This is the error the compiler is reporting to you; you obviously can't `&&` a function and a `Bool`.

If the compiler checked things in a different order it would also tell you that `x y` is not of type `Card`, and that `x` is not a function.