# My first Haskell program and I don't understand what's wrong

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement the `elem` function recursively. This is what I wrote:

```
 member :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
 member _ [] = False

 member n (x:xs)
     | n == x           = True : member (n xs)
     | otherwise        = False

 main = do
 print (member 10 [1,12,11])
```

I got a 'couldn't match expected type 'Bool' with actual type '[a0]' error.

I attempted the same using if..else..then as well, but in vain.

I think I'm missing out on a very basic and fundamental concept of Haskell here.

Help?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110605/couldnt-match-expected-type-bool-with-actual-type-card-bool?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087111/couldnt-match-expected-type-a0-with-actual-type-io?rq=1) didn't help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The clause `True : member (n xs)` does not match with `member`'s declared return type `Bool`. If you find an `x` in `xs` with `x == n`, then you want to simply return `True`.

Otherwise, you should recurse in `member` with a smaller list `xs` (i.e., check again for equality of `n` with the next element). Here is your code with these two problems fixed as described:

```
member n (x:xs) | n == x    = True
                | otherwise = member n xs
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `member n (x:xs) = n == x || member n xs`.

Answer (score 4):

- If you have found the element, the answer is `True`. You seem to be trying to create a list there, not sure why...
- If you haven't found it, recurse and check the tail...